# Handling Django Model Form Error in Ajax Submit

Tags: ajax, django, django-forms

I want to sumbit a model form with ajax and using model form validation messages:

```
class ComplaintForm(forms.ModelForm):
  class Meta:
      model = Complaint
      fields = [
          'title','body'
      ]


  def clean_body(self):
      form_data = self.cleaned_data
      body = self.cleaned_data.get('body', False)
      if len(body) < 2:
          raise forms.ValidationError(u'Please Add Complaint')
      return body

  def clean(self):
      cd = self.cleaned_data
      return cd
```

In my view:

```
def forms(request):
  form = ComplaintForm()
  if request.method == "POST":
      if request.is_ajax():
          form = ComplaintForm(request.POST)
          if form.is_valid():
              c = form.save(commit=False)
              c.user_ip = get_client_ip(request)
              c.user = request.user
              c.news =  news
              c.save()
              data = serializers.serialize('json', [c,])
          else:
              data = json.dumps([v for k,v in form.errors.items()])
              return HttpResponseBadRequest(data, mimetype='application/json')
          return HttpResponse(data, mimetype='application/json')

  else:
      form = ComplaintForm()

  return render_to_response('main/form.html', {'form': form},
                          context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

But, my problem is how could I send data through HttpResponseBadRequest ?
My js is:

```
$('.complaintform').submit(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/form/",
        dataType: "json",
        data: $(this).serialize(),
        success: function(data) {
            $('p').html('ok');                
        },
        error: function(data) {
           //how could i insert model form errors here?

        }
    });

});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Edited my answer. I misunderstood your question initially.

Try this:

```
$('.complaintform').submit(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/form/",
        dataType: "json",
        data: $(this).serialize(),
        success: function(data) {
            $('p').html('ok');                
        },
        statusCode: {
            400: function() {
                var items = [];
                $.each( data, function( val ) {
                items.push( val ); 
                });
                $('p').html(items.join(""));
            }
        }
    });

});
```

If that doesn't work, a dirty workaround would be: 
1) in the view:

```
else:
    data = json.dumps([v for k,v in form.errors.items()] + ['failed'])
    return HttpResponseBadRequest(data, mimetype='application/json')
```

2) in javascript:

```
success: function(data) {
    if jQuery.inArray("failed", data) {
        data.splice("failed", 1);
        var items = [];
        $.each( data, function( val ) {
            items.push( val ); 
        });
        $('p').html(items.join(""));
    } else {
        $('p').html('ok');
    }                
},
```

That will work if, for some strange reason, jquery thinks your HttpResponse is 'success'.

Comment: Thanks for response alex. My form template is:  {% load i18n %}
       {% for field in form %}
          <li id="{{ field.name }}" class="form-group">
          <label class="col-lg-3 control-label">{{ field.label_tag }}</label>
          <p></p>
          <div class="col-lg-8">
              {{ field }}
          </div>
      {% if field.errors %}
          <p>{{ field.errors }}</p>
      {% endif %}
      {% if field.help_text %}
        <p id="warning"><span class="control-label">{{ field.help_text|safe }}</span></p>
      {% endif %}
      </li>
  {% endfor %}

Comment: let's try then to specify the error code explicitly. please look at the updated code

Comment: jquery couldnt see the HttpBadRequest!! If form is not valid, data = json.dumps({'errors': dict([(k, [unicode(e) for e in v]) for k,v in form.errors.items()])}) . And I have to use this in success not error. Many thanks Alex.